# retrieve Datatables value for CSS formatting

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm building a table using `Datatables` picking up values from a database and would like to display rows that have `unread=true` in the database in **bold** text. I haven't found a way to retrieve any value (i.e **unread** column) from the table using Jquery/JS in order to apply a specific class.

Can this be done in any way? This is my current code, which obviously doesn't fix the problem.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on( 'shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
   $.fn.dataTable.tables( {visible: true, api: true} ).columns.adjust();
} );
var table = $('table.table').DataTable( {
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": {
     "dataSrc": "Data",
     "url": "logsController/getDataTable",
     "data": { string: $("input.form-control").val() },
     "type": "POST"
       },
       "columns": [
          { "data": "datetime" },
          { "data": "type" },
          { "data": "data" }
       ]
} );

$('#myTableLogs').DataTable();
```

`console.log(data.unread)` or `console.log(data.datetime)` both return "data is undefined"

**UPDATE:**
I solved my problem by removing the `serverSide` and changing my code. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [**createdRow callback option**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) to test the row data for a value and dynamically add a class to the row

```
var table = $('table.table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "dataSrc": "Data",
        "url": "logsController/getDataTable",
        "data": { string: $("input.form-control").val() },
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "datetime" },
        { "data": "type" },
        { "data": "data" }
    ],
    "createdRow": function(row, data) {
        // replace with appropriate reference to your data structure
        // and CSS class to change font weight
        if (data.unread) $(row).addClass('text-bold');
    }
});
```

Comment: That looks good but I get "data is not defined". I also tried to do a simple `console.log(data.type);` but I also get "data is not defined". How is the result from the function supposed to be retrieved?

Comment: Does the datatable work without the `"createdRow"` setting? and fails with it? try `console.log(data)`? i suspect there is another problem with your table. The `"serverSide"` option is a very advanced setting

Comment: Yes my table is displayed correctly without using `"createdRow"` and `console.log(data)` also returns undefined. I use `serverSide` because my data comes from a mysql database.

Comment: OK, so per the [**docs**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide) you're managing the filtering/paging/sorting on the server. I really can't be of more help without understanding the entire scope of what you are trying to implement including your server side management code as well as the full data model.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used the `createdRow` as you suggested but I needed to edit the rest of my code as well.

Comment: Glad you figured out the `serverSide` wasn't required. I see that issue here on SO quite a bit. It is an easily misunderstood setting. FWIW I think I answered your question correctly as the issue you were having was unrelated to the information provided and ultimately impossible to solve because it wasn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the serverSide wasn't required and inspired myself from [this page](http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.se/2015/08/jquery-datatables-get-data-from.html) and using [createdRow](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html).

```
$.ajax({
    url: "logsController/getDataTable",
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var table = $('#myTableLogs').DataTable({
            paging: true,
            sort: true,
            searching: true,
            data: data,
            ordering: true,
            columns: [
                 { "data": "datetime" },
                 { "data": "type" },
                 { "data": "data" },
                 { "data": "unread" }
            ],
             "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
                 if ( data.unread == 1 ) {
                      $('td', row).addClass('unread_class');
                 }
             }
        });
});
```